# Repeated measures - sort of?

Tags: regression, anova, repeated-measures, treatment-effect, control-group

I do mostly econometrics but am faced with a repeated measures type sample. I can solve it as a regression with dummies, but feel like I'm losing information in the repeated cases. I know the medical literature has many debates about the experimental design for these types of situations and would appreciate advice.

Suppose I have approximately 30 observations of a physical measure in a control group - say Meary's angle (MA). I do not have any repeated measures for the control group. In addition, I have 30 observations of MA for the treated group pre-op, at 6 months, and at 12 months.

I can simply create dummies for control/treated groups, 6 months, and 12 months, and run those against MA. Is there a better ANOVA-like approach that would capture the repeated measure aspect?

Comment: I'm confused. You have repeated measures for a treatment group but no repeated measures for the control group? If thats the case, why was this done in the first place?

Comment: I'm not the person who put together the data. I think it's an artifact of a poorly designed experiment.

Comment: I don't see any way to combine the control group and the treatment group and to keep the repeated observations. You could ditch the control group and use multilevel modelling to analyze just the treatment group data, but then again, then you don't have a control group.

Answer (score 1):

##### Suggestions

I think doing an analysis with your data is going to be fairly problematic without injecting a lot of limitations and confounding influence commentary into your discussion. The problem is that the control group does not have dependent data structures (to our knowledge) while the treatment group does. Basically any comparison between the two will be meaningless for the following reasons:

- To begin, you simply don't have enough observations. If one group has $n=30$ *subjects* while the other has $n=30$ *observations* (which I assume is split up by the subjects here), there will clearly be some power issues unless there are some large differences between groups (see Brysbaert, 2019; Brysbaert & Stevens, 2018, which discuss proper power in group comparisons as well as repeated measures designs). Unfortunately, even if you had enough power, it is not straightforward to estimate, as noted below.
- Because the treatment group was measured multiple times, the data will have correlated errors whereas the control group won't. As such, running a regular analysis on this would result in biased downwards standard error for the treatment group and will consequently be unreliable (Clarke, 2008). Similarly, running something like a mixed model on this (which accounts for the clustering of measurements for subjects) would have its own issues because you would essentially have conservative errors for the treatment group (the repeated measures are usable), so the groups would not be directly comparable.
- Beyond the mathematical issues present here, there are certain biases influencing this data that you will need to be able to explain, such as potential practice effects from whatever it was they were doing in this experiment (e.g. a memory task where over time they get better at recall simply due to exposure to the design). Particularly, because this is a secondary data analysis, your exposure to the data may influence the results, as the data is already fixed and known and you now know some characteristics of the data (Van den Akker, 2021).

Personally, I would either consider another avenue with this data or abandon it completely, but somebody else may hold a different opinion or provide some alternative methods that may be useful.

##### References

- Brysbaert, M. (2019). How many participants do we have to include in properly powered experiments? A tutorial of power analysis with reference tables. Journal of Cognition, 2(1), 1–38. https://doi.org/10.5334/joc.72
- Brysbaert, M., & Stevens, M. (2018). Power analysis and effect size in mixed effects models: A tutorial. Journal of Cognition, 1(1), 9. https://doi.org/10.5334/joc.10
- Clarke, P. (2008). When can group level clustering be ignored? Multilevel models versus single-level models with sparse data. Journal of Epidemiology & Community Health, 62(8), 752–758. https://doi.org/10.1136/jech.2007.060798
- Van den Akker, O. R., Weston, S., Campbell, L., Chopik, B., Damian, R., Davis-Kean, P., Hall, A., Kosie, J., Kruse, E., Olsen, J., Ritchie, S., Valentine, K., Van ’t Veer, A., & Bakker, M. (2021). Preregistration of secondary data analysis: A template and tutorial. Meta-Psychology, 5. https://doi.org/10.15626/MP.2020.2625